# Access all elements of an arraylist from an object which is stored in an arraylist (2 Dimentional)

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have several "student" objects in an arraylist, each student has an arraylist of courses. how do I access all of the courses from a particular student? Thanks in advance.

```
Scanner studentCourse = new Scanner(System.in);
int j = 0;

System.out.println("Which students course(s) do you want to view?");
for(Student l:listStudent) {
    System.out.print(j+1 + ")");
    System.out.println(l);
    j++;
}
int course = studentCourse.nextInt();

int k = s.listCourse.size();//need this to be the size of the correct array list
int l = 0;

while( l < k ){
    System.out.println(s.listCourse.get(0));//need this to print all of the elements in the correct array list
}

break;

public class Student {

    String studentFirstName, studentLastName;
    int studentID;
    double studentGPA;
    ArrayList<Course> listCourse = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very much understandable, but not your code.

```
Student student = studentList.get(indexPosition); 
//ArrayList gives this flexibility and that's the advantage of ArrayList over other Lists

if(student.getCoursesList()!=null && !student.getCoursesList().isEmpty()){
    for(Course course: student.getCoursesList()){
        System.out.println(course);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, my code has changed so many times I got all mixed up and thought I should post something at least. Everyone gets made when I don't post code haha.

Comment: It is saying that this line: Student student = studentList.get(indexPosition); is out of bound

Comment: I fixed the bounds issue, but for some reason nothing prints out. It just continues on with the main menu I made...

Comment: @Midi_, if you want your course to be printed directly, you need to implement `toString()` method in it or print any one of the properties of Course

Answer (score 1):

Look at using `for`

```
for (Course course : s.listCourse) {
  System.out.println(course);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getter` & `setter` methods in your `Student` class or just you use the `for` loop, as below.

```
for(Course course : s.listCourse) {
  System.out.println(course);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter for course. By using you can do following:

```
int len = s.listCourse.size();
for(int i = 0; i<=len; i++) {
    System.out.println(s.listCourse.get(i).getCourse());
}
```